# Triangular Multiplication Table

Tags: java, multiplication

I'm  new to Java. I'm trying to make a triangular multiplication table that looks somewhat like this:

Enter # of rows 7

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1
2   4
3   6   9
4   8   12  16  
5   10  15  20 25
6   12  18  24 30 36
7   14  21  28 35 42 49
```

Each row/column has to be numbered, and I have no idea how to do this. My code is seemingly waaay off, as I get an infinite loop that doesn't contain the correct values. Below you will find my code.

```
public class Prog166g
{
  public static void main(String args[])
   {
    int userInput, num = 1, c, d;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter # of rows "); // user will enter number that will define output's           parameters
    userInput = in.nextInt();

    boolean quit = true;
    while(quit)
    {
        if (userInput > 9)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
        for ( c = 1 ; c <= userInput ; c++ )
        { System.out.println(userInput*c);
          for (d = 1; d <= c; d++) // nested loop required to format numbers and "triangle" shape
          {
                System.out.print(EasyFormat.format(num,5,0));
          }
        }
    }
    }
   quit = false;
   }
}
```

EasyFormat refers to an external file that's supposed to format the chart correctly, so ignore that. If someone could please point me in the right direction as far as fixing my existing code and adding code to number the columns and rows, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two nested for loops will do the trick:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d\t", i);
}
System.out.println();
for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%d\t", i * j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
1   
2   4   
3   6   9   
4   8   12  16  
5   10  15  20  25  
6   12  18  24  30  36  
7   14  21  28  35  42  49
```

Comment: Thank you so much, man! That's exactly what I needed. How do I get the columns to be numbered as well? :)

Comment: Start by printing a (in a loop): `System.out.printf("%d\t", i);` between 1-7. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Again, thank you so much. I was struggling for the past hour or so with this program.

Comment: @Blackout621 sure thing buddy! One more tip: if you need to repeatedly use it - extract it to a separate method and you'll also get to increase the level of abstraction by providing `i` as an argument!

Comment: one more question... how come the program always prints 7 rows/columns regardless of user input?

Comment: Never mind, I got it! Just had to modify 8 to userInput within the loops.